# Infinite loop when redirecting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite

I have a sample page, let' say testpage.pl  When I choose English version, GET parameter is added to URL, like `/?language=en`.

Afterwards, when I click menu positions, they are in the English version so everything is OK.

But if I want to have English version of a subpage directlty after pasting  URL in a browser, like

> http://testpage.pl/wyjazdy-i-przyjazdy/erasmus-incoming-staff/accommodation.html)

the Polish version is opened. So I've made a simple redirect function like below, but it comes to the loop after first start. This function redirect to the same page, but before it tries to redirect to this first URL with GET parameter `?language=en`

How to solve this?

```js
function cleanUrl() {
  window.location = "http://testpage.pl/?language=en";
  var cleanedUrl = "http://testpage.pl/wyjazdy-i-przyjazdy/erasmus-incoming-staff/accommodation.html";
  var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  if (currentUrl !== cleanedUrl) {
    window.location = cleanedUrl;
  }

}
cleanUrl();
```

Comment: `window.location` will invoke a redirection and everything after it will not execcute

Answer (score 0):

Your are updating url in first line of function which is causing your code to loop infinite. Remove that line or move to some other function for fix

```
function cleanUrl() {
var cleanedUrl = "http://testpage.pl/wyjazdy-i-przyjazdy/erasmus-incoming-staff/accommodation.html";
var currentUrl =  "http://testpage.pl/?language=en";
if (currentUrl !== cleanedUrl) {
window.location = cleanedUrl;
}
}
cleanUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `window.location` assignment as last operation.

```
function cleanUrl() {
    var enUrl = "http://testpage.pl/?language=en";
    var cleanedUrl = "http://testpage.pl/wyjazdy-i-przyjazdy/erasmus-incoming-staff/accommodation.html";
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    if( currentUrl !== cleanedUrl ) { enUrl = cleanedUrl; }
    window.location = enUrl;
}
```